# Server knows that a message is coming from owner of a token?

Tags: blockchain, contract-design, ether, signature

So I am trying to understand ethereum better, am an amateur. So excuse my naivete  here. I am trying to think through this scenario to know if its possible, or how it could be implemented. If any of my current understandings are wrong please correct me.

Bob buys an NFT. On the ether blockchain you can now see the public address of Bob, the owner of the NFT.

Then I have a server running an API, and I want this server to only run a certain request on its API if the server can discern it is coming from Bob, the owner of that particular NFT.

Is there someway that Bob can sign a request sent to the server, so then the server can look at the public address of Bob on the NFT on the blockchain, and discern the request actually is coming from Bob?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want that Bob proves that he is Bob, the owner of the NFT, when he makes a request to your server. The server wants to be sure that the request was sent from Bob and not someone else pretending to be Bob.

The answer is yes, you can do this. To prove that he is indeed Bob, Bob should send a transaction to a smart contract that you deployed on the ethereum blockchain (or other blockchain supporting smart contracts). The fact that the transaction is coming from Bob's address prove that he is indeed Bob (only he could have signed it). Then, upon receiving that transaction, your smart contract can check if Bob's address owns that particular NFT. If he does, your smart contract will execute whatever you want, otherwise it will throw.

I would say that this is a very typical blockchain use case.

Comment: So Bob would add a new entry to the blockchain with some kind of token he generated. In the request to the server Bob would then send the blockchain address that holds that token. The server would then use that token to decode some other secret that Bob sends in the request to the server to validate its Bob? Is that correct? Does something like this exist already?

Comment: It's simpler than that. Bob would just need to send a transaction to the smart contract, but a transaction does not need to include a token. The smart contract would check if Bob has the nft in question in its account.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain. I still don't kind understand. Bob sends a transaction to a smart contract. But what kind of transaction, to what token type? How would the server then discern the request coming directly from Bob is actually from them?